# Mongodb array maching

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have the following document:

```
{ arr : [1,2,3] }
```

And I have to compare it with the following:

```
a : [1,2]

b : [2,3,1]

c : [2,5,3,1]
```

I need to make a query that return arr only when it match all the elements of the query array.

In the example, it would be "b" and "c"

I have tried with $all like the following:

```
find(arr:{$all:a}) (the same for b and c)
```

but this does not work because it match "a" too. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find( {$or:[
    { $and: [ { arr: 1 }, { arr: 2 }, {arr:{$size:2}} ] },
    { $and: [ { arr: 1 }, { arr: 2 }, { arr: 3 }, {arr:{$size:3}} ] },
    { $and: [ { arr: 1 }, { arr: 2 }, { arr: 3 }, { arr: 5 }, {arr:{$size:4}} ] }
]})
```

or maybe with the $all operator (i haven't tryied that before but should be ok):

```
find( {$or:[
    { $and: [ { arr: { $all: a } }, {arr:{$size: a.length }} ] },
    { $and: [ { arr: { $all: b } }, {arr:{$size: b.length }} ] },
    { $and: [ { arr: { $all: c } }, {arr:{$size: c.length }} ] }
]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation framework and its set operations to select arrays which are subsets of the query array:

```
> db.foo.insert({arr:[1,2,3]})
> db.foo.insert({arr:[3,2,1]})
> db.foo.insert({arr:[3,2,1,4]})
```

and then

```
 db.foo.aggregate([ 
    { $project: { arr:'$arr', isIn: { $setIsSubset: ['$arr', [2,5,3,1]] }}}, 
    { $match: { isIn: true }} 
])
```

returns

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5345beb536cdafd3eb4a6b16"), "arr" : [ 1, 2, 3 ], "isIn" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5345bec036cdafd3eb4a6b17"), "arr" : [ 3, 2, 1 ], "isIn" : true }
```

Note that this requires version 2.6+